# SQLite error in Java is not reproduced elsewhere

Tags: java, sql, database, sqlite

A java application I am working on uses local SQLite databases for certain data, using https://bitbucket.org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc version 3.8.10.2.

I parse data from an excel spreadsheet and then insert into the database. The request is built as such:

```
String request = "INSERT INTO 'table' ('col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'col5', 'col6', 'col7', 'col8', 'col9', 'col10') VALUES";

    for(Data d : dataToInsert){
        request += " ('" + d.getCol1().replaceAll("'", "''") +"', '" + d.getCol2().replaceAll("'", "''") +"', '" + d.getCol3().replaceAll("'", "''") +"', '" + d.getCol4().replaceAll("'", "''") +"', '" + d.getCol5().replaceAll("'", "''") +"', '" + d.getCol6().replaceAll("'", "''") +"', '" + d.getCol7().replaceAll("'", "''") +"', '" + d.getCol8().replaceAll("'", "''") +"', '" + d.getCol9().replaceAll("'", "''") +"', '" + d.getCol10().replaceAll("'", "''") +"'),";
    }

request = request .substring(0, request .length()-1) + ";";
```

The reason I do it this way is because I am inserting a large number of rows at once (approx 1475). Before running the update, I have it outputted via console so I have the completed request in my hands.

Running it via java causes this exception:

```
java.sql.SQLException: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (near ",": syntax error)
```

However, I am also using this app http://sqlitebrowser.org/ to monitor the database manually. Using the "Execute SQL" function in said app, the request I build with my code works, and the table is populated correctly.

What could cause the update request to work in said app and not when ran from the java application?

Comment: It would immensely helpful to you and us if you could post the string query from what you build above in your Java code.  My guess is that something will jump out at you immediately.